# MySQl:issue with select query

Tags: mysql, select

i need help with one query only, this is for example my table

```
id  time  status sid
1  10:00    0     1
2  12:00    0     2
3  11:00    1     1
4  13:00    1     2
```

( status 0 = login, status 1 = logout)
I want to know in one row users login and logout time.
The result of select query should look like this:

result:

```
id  time  time2   sid
1  10:00 11:00   1
2  12:00 13:00   2
```

The one row in result should contain same sid pair one that has status 0 and the next that has status 1 so that as a result i would have merged two times first is the login time of a user and the second is logout time?

Comment: what if we have more than 2 records of sid =1. Or you can say what if multiple login by a user than you will trace it? (need to update table structure)

Comment: The query should return one more row for that user because he can login multiple times the only problem is that I need to have his login and logout time in same row. I need to match his status 0 and status 1 for each of his sessions.

Comment: see me answer it will work for you.

Comment: This limits user to only one login but I users can have multiple logins so this is not working for me..

Comment: you table structure problem: 1) time should be timestamp or datetime 2) dont have relationship between login and logout to relate them.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming only single login for each user.

```
SELECT id,time,(select time from table C where M.sid=C.sid and status = 1 LIMIT 1),sid 
FROM table M WHERE status = 0
```

If you add one more column in you table to look like this:

```
id  time  status sid loginid 
11  10:00    0     1    0
12  12:00    0     2    0
13  11:00    1     1    11
14  13:00    1     2    12
```

Than you can have query like

```
SELECT id,time,(select time from table C where C.loginid=M.id),sid 
FROM table M WHERE status = 0
```

Comment: This will work for only one login per user, but I need to have all his logins.

Comment: You table structure need to modify to link between login/logout without than it will be difficult.

Comment: And even your time field does not store complete timestamp. .. :(

Comment: Timestamp is not an issue, I gave that time just as a example, problem is that I have to figure out something with this table structure that return multiple login sessions for same user.

Comment: updated my answer to have one more column and query.